# Python - TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, typeerror

BEGINNER in coding and currently on Python3, sorry to interrupt with this mock up I'm testing.

Got an TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' at line 3. Which I'm quite sure there are other errors after kindly shed lights, thanks!

```
def main():
    age = int(input ('Enter you age'))
if age<18:
    print ('Sorry')
else:
    print ('Welcome')
main()
```

Comment: Are you sure you have your indentation correct? When I run your code as I see it currently I get: `NameError: name 'age' is not defined`

Comment: You have an indentation error. Other than that, you have no other errors. However, I wouldn't add the space between the print function and the brackets.

Comment: Thanks all, fixed ident problem and works just fine now. Jupyter keeps saying it's a "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' [closed]" so got me confused.

Answer (score 3):

Your indentation is wrong, please fix that! Your code is fine

```
def main():
    age = int(input ('Enter you age'))
    if age<18:
        print ('Sorry')
    else:
        print ('Welcome')
main()
```

It is working fine for me

```
Enter you age12
Sorry
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the insight, Kuldeep Singh Sidhu !!!

Answer (score -2):

It works fine actually. As Kuldeep Singh Sidhu mentioned your identation is a problem. Or in the input you typed a string

Comment: Thanks for your time, N Sivaram!